# Classification of real vector spaces with $p$ endomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces

While reading the paper *From Groups to Groupoids: a survey* by Ronald Brown, I found this intriguing remark:

> [...] the classification of real vector spaces with $p$ endomorphisms is
>   interesting for $p = 1$, difficult for $p = 2$, and unsolved for $p = 3$. (I am grateful to A. Heller for this
>   trenchant expression of view.)

This seems a really interesting problem, I looked for papers and discussions regarding the case $p = 2$ but I couldn't find any.

Perhaps someone here can point me to the right keywords or authors I have missed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd want to search for/what you did search for. It's possible you want to look for classifications of modules over $\Bbb{R}[x,y]$, but it's hard to search for things containing LaTeX.

Comment: @jgon Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try with classification of modules, maybe this result is not stated explicitly in terms of vector spaces. I thought maybe this problem had a particular name or took the name of the person/people that worked on it.